# How can I compile Xilinx Vivado's simulation libraries for e.g. QuestaSim?

Tags: bash, xilinx, modelsim, vivado, questasim

I want to compile the Xilinx Vivado simulation primitives for QuestaSim (ModelSim). The documentation lists a TCL command, but I would like to use a common shell command like the old one for ISE:

```
<ISEDirectory>\bin\nt64\compxlib.exe -family all - language all -library all -simulator questa ....
```

As far as I can see, the TCL command should be entered in the Vivado GUI.

How can I run the compilation from an user defined PowerShell or Bash script?

Comment: PlanAhead has a TCL shell that presumably you could call compxlib from, maybe Vivado has a similar option. For reference, to enter PlanAhead interactive TCL shell use `planAhead -mode tcl` or to run a TCL script use `planAhead -mode batch -source <some/tcl/file>`

Comment: Yes, Vivado has a command line TCL shell, too. It's build into `Vivado.exe`. Is there no other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just to answer my own question for completeness ...*

There is no other way then running the compile command from the Vivado Tcl shell, either in the GUI or on command line.

**Compiling Vivado libraries from Bash:**

```
VSimBinDir=/opt/questasim/10.4d/bin
DestDir=xilinx-vivado

Simulator=questa
Language=vhdl
Library=all
Family=all

CommandFile=vivado.tcl

echo "compile_simlib -force -library $Library -family $Family -language $Language -simulator $Simulator -simulator_exec_path $VSimBinDir -directory $DestDir" > $CommandFile
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 -e "${COLORED_ERROR} Cannot create temporary tcl script.${ANSI_NOCOLOR}"
  exit -1;
fi
echo "exit" >> $CommandFile

# compile common libraries
$Vivado_tcl -mode tcl -source $CommandFile
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 -e "${COLORED_ERROR} Error while compiling Xilinx Vivado libraries.${ANSI_NOCOLOR}"
  exit -1;
fi
```